# How to receive the yes/no value from the alertDialog fragment to the actual activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialog

I need my app to test if the person clicks yes to continue or cancel to stop.
I have a AlertDialogFragment:

```
public class FragmentConfirmarPicagem extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Confirmar")
                .setMessage("Deseja mesmo picar o ponto agora?")
                .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

And then I have this code in the MainActivity: `new FragmentConfirmarPicagem().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Confirmar");`

I know the onClick of positive/negative buttons have that function but like that in the MainActivity I can't know the clicked button.

Basically what I want is:

```
    //if clicks Sim(Yes) does the following
        switch (verificarPonto()) {
            case 1:
                txtHoraEntrada.setText(hora);
                ponto.setEntrada(picagem);
                return;
            case 2:
                txtHoraSaidaAlmoco.setText(hora);
                ponto.setSaidaAlmoco(picagem);
                return;
            case 3:
                txtHoraEntradaTarde.setText(hora);
                ponto.setEntradaTarde(picagem);
                return;
            case 4:
                txtHoraSaida.setText(hora);
                ponto.setSaida(picagem);
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to create a new class for a Dialog ?

You can do it directly from your activity

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisActivity)
                    .setTitle("Confirmar")
                    .setMessage("Deseja mesmo picar o ponto agora?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (verificarPonto()) {
                                case 1:
                                    txtHoraEntrada.setText(hora);
                                    ponto.setEntrada(picagem);
                                   return;
                                ...
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
            builder.create().show();
```

If for some reason you need to create a new class, you can do it like this

```
public static class FragmentConfirmarPicagem extends DialogFragment {
    public  DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Confirmar")
                .setMessage("Deseja mesmo picar o ponto agora?")
                .setPositiveButton("Sim", listener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

then, in your activity

```
            FragmentConfirmarPicagem fcp = new FragmentConfirmarPicagem();
            fcp.listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (verificarPonto()) {
                            case 1:
                                txtHoraEntrada.setText(hora);
                                ponto.setEntrada(picagem);
                               return;
                            ...
                        }                    
                    }
                };
                fcp.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Confirmar");
```

Comment: i tried your first example and it gives this error: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: I think you are calling your Dialog too early. Are you calling the Dialog in your onCreate() method?

Comment: I am calling it in click() of a button wich is in onCreate()

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisActivity)` what are you using for `thisActivity`?

Comment: `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Use `YourActivityName.this` instead.

Comment: thank you, I thought I already had tried that, and it did nothing, but now it's working.